# mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in php

Tags: php

DbOperations.php

```
    public function getGender($id)
    {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("select gender, dob_year from table_user where id = '$id'");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $gender, $dob_year);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

data.php

```
<?php
require_once 'database_config/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

$id = $_POST['id'];

$db = new DbOperations();

$user = $db->getGender($id);

$response['gender'] = $user['gender'];
$response['dob_year'] = $user['dob_year'];

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Hi, I am trying to get dob_year and gender information from an "id" input. but it gives a warning

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

What can be the reason??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be like this

```
public function getGender($id)
    {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("select gender, dob_year from table_user where id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

Comment: oh thank you so much!! it solved. I can accept this answer after 10 minutes.